# Visual Studio 2015: debugging MVC controller

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, office-js

I'm developing a Word Add-in and I changed the default web project to a custom ASP.NET MVC project. I tried adding a breakpoint to a certain method on controller but it's not reached.

Is there something I could do to debug the server side C# code, as if it were a normal web project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To debug a MVC solution:

Attach to Running Processes with the Visual Studio Debugger:

1. Build your solution and open your site on any web browser.
2. Place your breakpoint(s) in your server side code.
3. Under **Debug** > Choose **Attach to process** (Or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>)
4. In the process list, choose the **w3wp.exe** or **iisexpress.exe** process (depending on your project type), and click **attach**.
5. Wait for visual Studio to load all relevant symbols referenced by your project (this might take a while).
6. Once all symbols are loaded, the debug point should turn **Red**.

This means that you can now use your web site and reach an active breakpoint.

Comment: @jeanie77 Happy to help! Happy coding, peace and love.